# 'View v' has incomplete type and cannot be defined C++

Tags: c++, oop

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

class Contact;
class Controller;
class View;

class Contact {
private:
    std::string name;
    std::string phone;
public:
    std::string get_name() {
        return name;
    }
    std::string get_phone() {
        return phone;
    }
    void set_name(std::string name) {
        this->name = name;
    }
    void set_phone(std::string phone) {
        this->phone = phone;
    }
};

class Controller {
public:
    void delete_contact(std::vector<Contact> &data) {
        std::cout << "Choose a number from 1 to 3.\n";
        std::cout << "1. Delete by id\n";
        std::cout << "2. Delete by name\n";
        std::cout << "3. Delte by phone\n";
        int choice;
        std::cin >> choice;
        enum { ID = 1, NAME = 2, PHONE = 3 };
        if (choice == ID) {
            int id;
            std::cout << "Enter id: \n";
            std::cin >> id;
            delete_by_id(data, id);
        }
        else if (choice == NAME) {
            std::string name;
            std::cout << "Enter name: \n";
            std::cin >> name;
            delete_by_name(data, name);
        }
        else if (choice == PHONE) {
            std::string phone;
            std::cout << "Enter phone: \n";
            std::cin >> phone;
            delete_by_phone(data, phone);
        }
        else {
            std::cerr << "Wrong choice.\n";
        }

    }
    void delete_by_id(std::vector<Contact> &data, const int id) {
        // valid ids are in range [1 .. data.size()]
        if (id < data.size() || id > data.size()) {
            std::cerr << "id not found\n";
            return;
        }
        std::cout << "Contact " << id << " deleted successfully\n";
    }
    void delete_by_name(std::vector<Contact> &data, const std::string name) {
        int id = -1;
        // assuming unique names
        for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++) {
            if (data[i].get_name() == name) {
                id = i;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (id == -1) {
            std::cerr << "Contact with " << name << " is not found\n";
            return;
        }
        data.erase(data.begin() + id);
    }
    void delete_by_phone(std::vector<Contact> &data, const std::string phone) {
        int id = -1;
        for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++) {
            if (data[i].get_name() == phone) {
                id = i;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (id == -1) {
            std::cerr << "Contact with " << phone << " is not found\n";
            return;
        }
        data.erase(data.begin() + id);
    }
    void add_contact(Contact new_contact, std::vector<Contact> &data) {
        data.push_back(new_contact);
    }
    void search_contact(std::vector<Contact> &data) {
        std::cout << "1. Search by id.\n";
        std::cout << "2. Search by name.\n";
        std::cout << "3. Search by phone.\n";
        enum { ID = 1, NAME = 2, PHONE = 3 };
        int choice;
        std::cin >> choice;
        if (choice == ID) {
            int id;
            std::cout << "Enter id: \n";
            std::cin >> id;
            search_by_id(data, id);
        }
        else if (choice == NAME) {
            std::string name;
            std::cout << "Enter name: \n";
            std::cin >> name;
            search_by_name(data, name);
        }
        else if (choice == PHONE) {
            std::string phone;
            std::cout << "Enter phone: \n";
            std::cin >> phone;
            search_by_phone(data, phone);
        }
        else {
            std::cerr << "Wrong choice.\n";
        }


    }
    void search_by_id(std::vector<Contact> &data, int id) {
        if (id < data.size() || id > data.size()) {
            std::cerr << "Contact not found\n";
            return;
        }
        View v;
        v.print_contact_data(data[id]);

    }
    void search_by_name(std::vector<Contact> &data, const std::string name) {
        int id = -1;
        for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++) {
            if (data[i].get_name() == name) {
                id = i;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (id == -1) {
            std::cerr << "Contact not found\n";
            return;
        }
        View v;
        v.print_contact_data(data[id]);
    }
    void search_by_phone(std::vector<Contact> &data, const std::string phone) {
        int id = -1;
        for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++) {
            if (data[i].get_phone() == phone) {
                id = i;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (id == -1) {
            std::cerr << "Contact not found\n";
            return;
        }
        View v;
        v.print_contact_data(data[id]);
    }
    void edit_contact(std::vector<Contact> &data) {
        std::cout << "Enter contact id\n";
        int id;
        std::cin >> id;
        if (id < data.size() || id > data.size()) {
            std::cerr << "Sorry, wrong id\n";
        }
        std::cout << "Do you want to edit this contact? [Y, N]\n";
        View v;
        v.print_contact_data(data[id]);
        std::string choice;
        std::cin >> choice;
        if (choice.front() == 'Y') {
            std::cout << "Enter new name:\n";
            std::string name;
            std::cin >> name;
            data[id].set_name(name);
            std::cout << "Enter new phone:\n";
            std::string phone;
            std::cin >> phone;
            data[id].set_phone(phone);
            std::cout << "Done\n";

        }
        else {
            std::cerr << "Wrong choice.\n";
        }

    }
};

class View {
public:
    
    std::vector<Contact> data;
    void print_contact_data(Contact data) {
        std::cout << data.get_name() << ' ' << data.get_phone() << '\n';
    }
    void print_all_contacts() {
        int curr = 1;
        for (auto x : data)
            std::cout << curr++ << ". " << x.get_name() 
            << ' ' << x.get_phone() << '\n';

    }
    Contact get_contact_data() {
        Contact data;
        std::cout << "Enter contact name:\n";
        std::string name;
        std::cin >> name;
        std::cout << "Enter contact phone:\n";
        std::string phone;
        std::cin >> phone;
        data.set_name(name);
        data.set_phone(phone);
        return data;

    }
    void main_menu() {
        enum { ADD = 1, DELETE = 2, EDIT = 3,
            SEARCH = 4, PRINT = 5, EXIT = 6 };
        std::cout << "1. Add contact\n";
        std::cout << "2. Delete contact\n";
        std::cout << "3. Edit contact\n";
        std::cout << "4. Search contact\n";
        std::cout << "5. Print all contacts\n";
        std::cout << "6. Exit\n";
        int choice;
        std::cin >> choice;
        Controller temp;
        if (choice == ADD) {

            temp.add_contact(get_contact_data(), data);

        } else if (choice == DELETE) {
            temp.delete_contact(data);
            
        } else if (choice == EDIT) {
            temp.edit_contact(data);
        } else if (choice == SEARCH) {
            temp.search_contact(data);
        } else if (choice == PRINT) {
            print_all_contacts();
        } else if (choice == EXIT) {
            exit(0);
        } else {
            std::cout << "Wrong choice\n";
        }

    }
};



int main() {
    View v;
    v.main_menu();
    return 0;
}
```

I've tried to implement MVC design pattern. Basically, this is a basic contact management system. One can add, delete, edit, search contacts. View class is responsible for user manipulation and interacts with the user. The contact class is just the model. I'm getting this error message "'View v' has incomplete type and cannot be defined". I've searched for some solutions but couldn't find what my error is.

Comment: You are using `View` before it's defined. Just move your member function definitions outside of the class, and after `View` is defined.

Comment: @cigien But there are class definitions after includes, wouldn't this make`View` visible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the following code structure:

```
class Contact;
class Controller;
class View;

class Controller {
public:
    // ...
    void search_by_id(std::vector<Contact> &data, int id) {
        // ...
        View v;
        // ...
    }
    // ...
};

class View {
public:
    // ...    
    void main_menu() {
        // ...
        Controller temp;
        // ...
    }
    // ...
};
```

This gives an error because `View v;` requires `View` to be defined. Moving the definition of `View` to before `Controller` won't solve the issue because `Controller temp;` would have the same issue.

The simple fix is to move all the function definitions outside the class, and after the other classes have been defined:

```
class Controller {
public:
    // ...
    void search_by_id(std::vector<Contact> &data, int id);
    // ... 
};

class View {
public:
    // ...
    void main_menu();
    // ...
};

void View::main_menu() {
    // ...
    Controller temp;
    // ...
}

void Controller::search_by_id(std::vector<Contact> &data, int id) {
    // ...
    View v;
    // ...
}
```